# What would happen if I increase the ping packet size

Tags: networking, command-line, cmd.exe, ping

I am a newbie to this networking thing and I wonder something that if I increase the ping size to 65.600, how does it affect the internet traffic?

```
ping –1 65500 [IP address]
```

Comment: Trivia: [ping of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death).

Comment: Is it `65600` or `65500`? There's a substantial difference. Ping `localhost` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Your computer is probably connected to some form of wired or wireless Ethernet where the standard MTU is just 1500 bytes, so your giant ICMP Echo Request datagram would get fragmented at the IP layer into something like 40+ fragment packets before being transmitted. If all those fragments reach the destination, it will reply with a giant fragmented datagram of its own, and if all those fragments make it back to you, your ping tool will show a successful ping.